# CefSharp ctrl+f5

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I have a CefSharp browser on my WPF page. It has cached some javascript/HTML. How can I clear the cache? In the browser, I would use "ctrl + f5". I really when the component is loaded I would want to get a fresh version of the files each time.

Comment: You can reload ignoring the cache see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/93.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_Reload_1.htm